Metric filter for cloudwatch logs
I want to create a CloudWatch alarm on this particular chunk: close "/uploads/reporting
This is the complete log statement.
"Nov 11 11:11:11 ip-111-11-11-1 sshd[14]: close "/uploads/reporting/114/14_Extended log.csv" bytes read 0 written 786"
When I test it out using the console it works on this filter pattern "close "/uploads/reporting/" but cloudformation raises syntax error on this during deployment.
What filter pattern can I use. So far i have tried:
'[w1="close", w2="uploads/reporting"]'
"close /uploads/reporting/"
and a lot of other stuff but it does not trigger the alarm correctly. What am I doing wrong?

It would be helpful to see the exact syntax error message, but I'm guessing this is because you have a double quote inside a double quoted string.
